# Media Response in Custom Payload (Dialogflow)

Tags: actions-on-google

I'm trying to code a Media Response in a Custom Payload with no luck. I'm surely doing something wrong but I have no idea :) The Media Response does not show up when testing. (Please note that I'm trying this in an english action).  Here's the JSON code:

```
{
  "platform": "google",
  "type": "custom_payload",
  "payload": {
    "google": {
      "richResponse": {
        "items": [
          {
            "mediaResponse": {
              "mediaType": "AUDIO",
              "mediaObjects": [
                {
                  "name": "Exercises",
                  "description": "ex",
                  "largeImage": {
                    "url": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/...",
                    "accessibilityText": "image..."
                  },
                  "contentUrl": "https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
                }
              ]
            }
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}
```

UPDATE:

I've updated the JSON to something like this. But I get an error :"API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: ": Cannot find field."

```
{
"platform":"google",
"type":"custom_payload",
"payload":{
  "google":{
     "richResponse":{
        "items":[
           {
              "simpleResponse":{
                 "textToSpeech":"Hey! Good to see you."
              }
           },
           {
              "mediaResponse":{
                 "mediaType":"AUDIO",
                 "mediaObjects":[
                    {
                       "name":"Exercises",
                       "description":"ex",
                       "largeImage":{
                          "url":"https://firebasestorage...",
                          "accessibilityText":"..."
                       },
                       "contentUrl":"https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/..."
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        ],
        "suggestions":[
           {
              "title":"chips"
           }
        ]
     }
  }
```

And here's the debug information:

```
{
 "audioResponse": "//NExAARWG...",
 "conversationToken": "GidzaW11bG...",
 "debugInfo": {
  "agentToAssistantDebug": {
  "agentToAssistantJson": "{\"message\":\"Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse, exception thrown with message: Empty speech response\",\"apiResponse\":{\"id\":\"cd7204ac-ab80-42aa-9755-6123cbb938a6\",\"timestamp\":\"2018-03-11T09:02:35.827Z\",\"lang\":\"en-us\",\"result\":{},\"status\":{\"code\":200,\"errorType\":\"success\"},\"sessionId\":\"1520758955600\"}}"
},
"assistantToAgentDebug": {
  "assistantToAgentJson": "{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"AA9douaa4XGkqtmcU_EDjPy7PQ_9\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-03-11T09:02:09Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1520758955600\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"Talk to Zen Coach\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}",
  "curlCommand": "curl -v 'https://api.api.ai/api/integrations/google?token=0def1bb6be4b4bf2810ec68bf6f37a6a' -H 'Content-Type: application/json;charset=UTF-8' -H 'Google-Actions-API-Version: 2' -H 'Authorization: eyJhbGciOiJSUzI1NiIsImtpZCI6ImFjMmI2M2ZhZWZjZjgzNjJmNGM1MjhlN2M3ODQzMzg3OTM4NzAxNmIifQ.eyJhdWQiOiJ6ZW4tY29hY2giLCJhenAiOiI0OTYwOTIwOTE1NzEtMGNhY3VtczVkZ3F1OWpkM2k0dHZpOGFiOTVydXQ2NnQuYXBwcy5nb29nbGV1c2VyY29udGVudC5jb20iLCJleHAiOjE1MjA3NTkwNzUsImlzcyI6Imh0dHBzOi8vYWNjb3VudHMuZ29vZ2xlLmNvbSIsImp0aSI6IjY4NDc0NThhNTNhZGExODAxZjMwMjAyYjkxZGIyODZhMjk1NzA2YmIiLCJpYXQiOjE1MjA3NTg5NTUsIm5iZiI6MTUyMDc1ODY1NX0.e1cqg96F5L-BvD0yJz3UFgsnX_0TRox0Lu8R9K5NhhXcQVfC7mq1QwCqs2DGrUJGquGdW2GhzBU2lzf4ro2TUeieg4ozak1OmiYAMqtiCH0EodeHy59AXXqzb3a35YuD7CmSDu6qVQRfEp8uaaH2t-Sq9lUchudNOgjucip3ex9Rr2XacHm0qWtV69H1o-Yq5INl5HHR0kNqtEIsxUox961imKvDLN5s--F35yTbAhIWibr6OmaACyzSQW5X7OjrJ2781DSmEdYn73poDbuwMS9E2l9B-QTUHAIpUM5b4WqrFkD6XKALdf2pQFwZlRRhDzRiDKWLA-i1w-mcak0LWw'  -A 'Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; Google-Cloud-Functions/2.1; +http://www.google.com/bot.html)' -X POST -d '{\"user\":{\"userId\":\"AA9douaa4XGkqtmcU_EDjPy7PQ_9\",\"locale\":\"en-US\",\"lastSeen\":\"2018-03-11T09:02:09Z\"},\"conversation\":{\"conversationId\":\"1520758955600\",\"type\":\"NEW\"},\"inputs\":[{\"intent\":\"actions.intent.MAIN\",\"rawInputs\":[{\"inputType\":\"VOICE\",\"query\":\"Talk to Zen Coach\"}]}],\"surface\":{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.MEDIA_RESPONSE_AUDIO\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.WEB_BROWSER\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]},\"isInSandbox\":true,\"availableSurfaces\":[{\"capabilities\":[{\"name\":\"actions.capability.SCREEN_OUTPUT\"},{\"name\":\"actions.capability.AUDIO_OUTPUT\"}]}]}'"
},
"sharedDebugInfo": [
  {
    "name": "ResponseValidation",
    "subDebugEntry": [
      {
        "debugInfo": "API Version 2: Failed to parse JSON response string with 'INVALID_ARGUMENT' error: \": Cannot find field.\".",
        "name": "UnparseableJsonResponse"
      }
    ]
  }
]
},
"response": "Zen coach isn't responding right now. Try again soon.",
"visualResponse": {
"visualElements": []
}
}
```

Comment: Can you update your answer to include the output of the "debug" tab from the simulator? Can you also confirm that you're using Dialogflow v2?

Comment: Yes, I'm using Dialogflow V2 but I tried also v1. Same issue.

Comment: What does the debug screen look like for Dialogflow v1?

Comment: OH! Hang on. This is the "Custom Payload" in the Dialogflow response tab? Not being sent from a webhook?

Comment: Yes, this is the Custom Payload in the Dialogflow respond tab. My bad that I've not written it earlier :(

Answer (score 5):

Are you adding "platform":"google" and "type":"custom_payload" in the custom payload? If so, try removing that.

I made the following work with my Voice Metronome application:

```
{
  "google":{
     "richResponse":{
        "items":[
           {
              "simpleResponse":{
                 "textToSpeech":"Hey! Good to see you."
              }
           },
           {
              "mediaResponse":{
                 "mediaType":"AUDIO",
                 "mediaObjects":[
                    {
                       "name":"Exercises",
                       "description":"ex",
                       "largeImage":{
                          "url":"http://res.freestockphotos.biz/pictures/17/17903-balloons-pv.jpg",
                          "accessibilityText":"..."
                       },
                       "contentUrl":"https://freepd.com/Chill/Chill Air.mp3"
                    }
                 ]
              }
           }
        ],
        "suggestions":[
           {
              "title":"chips"
           }
        ]
     }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The issue is that the `richResponse` property still needs to follow the rules of the [RichResponse](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#richresponse) object. The first item in it must be a [SimpleResponse](https://developers.google.com/actions/reference/rest/Shared.Types/AppResponse#simpleresponse) object. (I haven't tested, but you can probably have that say nothing, but it is a good spot to have an introduction to your audio.)

The error message `Failed to parse Dialogflow response into AppResponse, exception thrown with message: Empty speech response` suggests that it might also be looking for a `speech` parameter on the top-level object in the response, which is what Dialogflow v1 expects to duplicate either the `simpleResponse` `ssml` or `textToSpeech` parameters. I'm not sure why that would appear if you're set to v2, but it sounds like something might be confused there. I would make sure you're using v1 and that you have a `speech` parameter.

Also keep in mind that the [reviewers will look for suggestion chips](https://developers.google.com/actions/assistant/responses#building_apps_with_media_responses) about how to move the conversation forward during or after the audio if this isn't a final response.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try and I'll tell you ;) Btw, I think that suggestion chips are not required if the media response is the end of the conversation, like in my case. (Right?)

Comment: correct - suggestion chips are only necessary if you're continuing the conversation.

Comment: Updated, but your error doesn't match that you're using v2.

Comment: @Prisoner i'm getting v1 errors in response to v2 requests as well.

Comment: @DanielSmith - I'd suggest posting your details as a new question. In particular, I'd suggest posting which v1 and v2 you think you're using (Actions on Google v1/v2 or Dialogflow v1/v2), the JSON you're returning in your webhook, the debugging you're seeing in the simulator, and any other details you can.

Comment: @Prisoner I don't really have a question. Just an observation. For example, MalformedResponse of ResponseValidation returns the following from debug when using Dialogflow v2beta1 with Conversation v2. I know I’m on v2 because I created the agent after May of 2017. As of v2, elements are camelCase not underscore separated. Although this isn’t a critical bug, it causes confusion for new developers.

```expected_inputs[0].input_prompt.rich_initial_prompt: the first element must be a 'simple_response', a 'structured_response' or a 'custom_response’.```